# Firebase logout generates a login page

Tags: angular, firebase, google-authentication

I have this Angular 6 project where I'm trying to add a login/logout feature using Firebase. Here is my code:

```
isLoggedIn = false;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.uid = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    map(authState => {
     if (!authState) {
       return null;
     } else {
       this.isLoggedIn = true;
       return authState.uid;
     }
   }),
  );
}

login() {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(() => {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      console.log(1234, this.isLoggedIn);
    });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
  }
}

logout() {
  try {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
      console.log(4321, this.isLoggedIn);
    });
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
  }
}

<button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
<button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="login()">Log In</button>
```

My issue is that when I hit the logout button is seems to log out the user as the login button shows up but then a new login pop up opens up. What am I doing wrong. If you have any questions don't hesitate to comment as I'm super responsive.

Answer (score 0):

(Is this the whole working code?) Aside from the user scenario being that a double click is happening (logout then login immediately), I don't see anything that should retrigger the login.

Instead of manually setting the "isLoggedIn" in your login/logout methods, you can stay subscribed to the authState for this (the subscribe in your constructor is doing most of this already, should be the ngOnInit). Using the authState to drive this is a good idea because if a login or logout fails, the isLoggedIn variable won't be out of sync with the actual authState.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        tap((user: User | null) =>
            this.isLoggedIn = user !== null
        ),
    ).subscribe();
    // either store the subscription and unsubscribe in destroy,
    // or implement something like takeUntil and the subject to cancel on destroy
}
```

---

If you feel the UI is changing too quickly, you can add a loading state possibly with a forced delay so it's clear what the UI is doing. The below example uses the user action to set the loading state (waiting for something to happen), and the subscription to the auth state updates the "isLoggedIn", then forces a delay before setting the loading state back to false.

```
loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

isLoggedIn = false;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        tap((user: User | null) =>
            this.isLoggedIn = user !== null
        ),
        delay(300),
        tap(() =>
            this.loadingSubject.next(false)
        ),
    ).subscribe();
    // either store the subscription and unsubscribe in destroy,
    // or implement something like takeUntil and the subject to cancel on destroy
}

login() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

logout() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}



<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="loading$ | async; else buttons" [mode]="'indeterminate'"></mat-progress-spinner>

<ng-template #buttons>
    <button *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="logout()">Log Out</button>
    <button *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" (click)="login()">Log In</button>
</ng-template>
```